# Is it a UUOC (useless use of cat) to redirect one file to another?

Tags: files, io-redirection, file-copy, cat

If I want to make the contents of `file2` match the contents of `file1`, I could obviously just run `cp file1 file2`.

However, if I want to preserve *everything* about `file2` *except* the contents—owner, permissions, extended attributes, ACLs, hard links, etc., etc., then I wouldn't want to run `cp`.*  In that case I just want to plop the contents of `file1` into `file2`.

It seems like the following would do it:

```
< file1 > file2
```

But it doesn't work.  `file2` is truncated to nothing and not written to.  However,

```
cat < file1 > file2
```

*does* work.

It surprised me that the first version doesn't work.

Is the second version a UUOC?  Is there a way to do this without invoking a command, merely by using redirections?

<sub>Note: I'm aware that UUOC is more of a pedantic point than a true anti-pattern.</sub>

*<sub>As [tniles09 discovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249811/135943), `cp` *will* in fact work in this case.</sub>

Comment: Whether `< file1 > file2` does what you want is shell-dependent.

Comment: Well, it *is* a Useless Use of `<`...

Comment: what's an *anti-pattern*?

Comment: @mikeserv https://www.google.com/search?q=anti-pattern

Comment: @jwodder - that's not true. especially when you're talking about a copy. consider what happens when `file1` doesn't exist or else is unreadable and you open it with `<` *before* `>` output is opened, and then consider what happens when you allow `cat` to try to open it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: In which shell does the redirection (only) do the copying?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In zsh an empty command with redirections invokes `cat` (by default), essentially running the second command. See [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249872/73093) below for more on that than fits in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: Thanks.  I've learned something.  I'm not sure I consider it a selling point for `zsh`, but that's way outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: @DigitalChris What's a rhetorical question?

Comment: @glglgl did I miss some kind of inside joke?

Comment: @DigitalChris if giggle is talking about me, not exactly. i had honestly never heard the word before and followed the link through to wikipedia and whatever. i guess its some kind of geek thing, but i didn't know. anyway, the word itself is kind of meaningless... that is a *weird* word. it suggests a set of regular occurrences that cancels the form of their regular occurrence.

Comment: @mikeserv, a couple example usages of the word anti-pattern that you're likely to understand: `curl -s <url> | sudo bash` is very much an anti-pattern though I have even seen it in software install instructions.  In `vi`, staying in insert mode all the time and using arrow keys to navigate is an anti-pattern.  And, this famous question is on the subject of a very common `bash` anti-pattern: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943

Comment: wc - i get it now - like i said, i checked wikipedia. but i still think the word is *weird*. it's self-contradictory - *anti-pattern* is an *anti-pattern*.

Comment: @glglgl - https://www.google.com/search?q=rhetorical

Comment: Wow, way to completely disappoint me when I clicked the title of this question on the Hot Network Questions list. So much for coming to see a cat!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`cat < file1 > file2` is not a UUOC. Classically, `<` and `>` do redirections which correspond to file descriptor duplications at the system level.
File descriptor duplications by themselves don’t do a thing (well, `>` redirections open with `O_TRUNC`, so to be accurate, output redirections do truncate the output file). Don’t let the `<` `>` symbols confuse you. Redirections don’t move data—they assign file descriptors to other file descriptors.

In this case you open `file1` and assign that file descriptor to file descriptor `0` (`<file1` == `0<file1`) and `file2` and assign that file descriptor to file descriptor `1` (`>file2` == `1>file2`).

Now that you’ve got two file descriptors, you need a process to shovel data between the two—and that’s what `cat` is for.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but my favorite part of this answer is your use of the word "shovel."  :)  Very clear, thank you.

Comment: @Wildcard I'd have preferred "pump" over "shovel", but still a good word. +1

Comment: why is shovel a good word?

Comment: One shovels a pile of dirt, one shovel full at a time, from one pile to another as data is copied buffer by buffer. It's a good analogy.

Comment: In your first sentence, you say the file descriptors are being duplicated.  Are they being duplicated or reassigned (as your second paragraph, and the behavior of the feature, seem to indicate)?

Answer (score 17):

It is not, because as others have pointed out, the behavior in question is shell-dependent. As you (the OP) have pointed out, this is a bit of a [pedantic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html), maybe even [humorous?](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), sort of topic.

However, on GNU systems, your initial premise has another solution available: `cp --no-preserve=all file1 file2`. Try this out, I think it will satisfy your described situation (e.g. modifying contents of `file2` while not modifying its attributes).

**Example**:

```
$ ls -l
    total 8
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tniles sambashare 16 Dec 16 12:21 fezzik
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tniles tniles     14 Dec 16 12:16 fred
$ cat *
    Lookout, world!
    Hello, world!
$ cp --no-preserve=all fred fezzik 
$ ls -l
    total 8
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tniles sambashare 14 Dec 16 12:22 fezzik
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tniles tniles     14 Dec 16 12:16 fred
$ cat *
    Hello, world!
    Hello, world!
```

**UPDATE**
Actually, I just noticed that my system's `cp` by itself seems to preserve attributes unless `-a` or `-p` are specified. I'm using bash shell and GNU coreutils. *I guess you learn something new everyday...*

---

Test results (by Wildcard) including hard link and different permissions:

```
$ ls -li
total 12
913966 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:26 file1
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 39 Dec 16 20:35 file2
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 39 Dec 16 20:35 hardlinktofile2
$ cat file1
This is the contents of file1
$ cat file2
This is the original contents of file2
$ cp file1 file2
$ ls -li
total 12
913966 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:26 file1
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:37 file2
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:37 hardlinktofile2
$ cat file1
This is the contents of file1
$ cat file2
This is the contents of file1
$
```

Comment: Nice.  I ran my own test including a hard link and different permissions and it seems that you're correct.

Comment: Added my test results; hope you don't mind.  :)  I didn't test ACLs or extended attributes but given that the *inode number* is preserved I'm 99% sure those would be also.

Comment: Nice... don't mind at all. :-)

Answer (score 14):

In `zsh`, the shell where `< file1 > file2` works, the shell does invoke `cat`.

For a command line that consists only of redirections and no command nor assignments, `zsh` invokes `$NULLCMD` (`cat` by default) unless the only redirection is a `<` one in which case `$READNULLCMD` (`pager` by default) is invoked instead. (that's unless `zsh` is in `sh` or `csh` emulation in which case it behaves like the shells it emulates).

So:

```
< file1 > file2
```

is actually the same as

```
cat < file1 > file2
```

and

```
< file1
```

is the same as

```
pager < file1
```

Comment: For the record, this syntax does not work for ksh93

Answer (score 8):

```
< from > to
```

doesn't work because there is no command there; no process. The shell opens/creates the files and arranges the redirections (meaning that the file descriptors referencing these files are planted as 0 and 1: standard input and standard output). But there is nothing there to do execute a loop to read from standard input and write to standard output.

`zsh` makes this work by substituting a user-configurable command in this "null command" case. The command is not visible in the command line, but it's still there. A process is created for it and it works the same way. `NULLCMD` is `cat` by default, so `< from > to` actually *means* `cat < from > to` in `zsh`, unless `NULLCMD` is set to something else; it is an "implicit cat" command.

A "useless use of cat" occurs when `cat` is used as an intermediary to read from a file and feed the data to another process, whose file descriptor could just be connected to the original file.

If `cat` is removable from the situation, such that the remaining commands can still perform the same task, it is useless. If it is not removable, then it isn't useless.

```
# useless, removable:
$ cat archive.tar | tar tf -    #  -->  tar tf archive.tar

# not removable (in POSIX shell):
$ cat > file
abc
[Ctrl-D]

# likewise:
STRING=$(cat file)
```

A `cat` that is *replacable* isn't the same thing. For instance instead of `cat > file` we can use `vi file` to create the file. That's doesn't count as removal of `cat`, while using whatever is left to achieve the same task.

If `cat` is the *only* command in the pipeline, then of course it can't be removed; no rearrangement of whatever is left will do the equivalent job.

Some shell scripters use `cat` because they think it lets them move the input operand closer to the left side of the command line. However, redirections can be anywhere in the command line:

```
# If you're so inclined:
# move source archive operand to the left without cat:
$ < archive.tar tar xf - > listing
```

Comment: btw, you don't have to use `f -` for tar. `tar xf -` is just `tar x`.

Comment: @mikeserv  Where does it say that `cat` is involved in the file creation? Answer clearly says that the shell does this. What problem with `> file` are you referring to? I often use it alone for truncating an existing file to zero length or ensuring such exists. This question is about why `< from > to` doesn't work like `cat < from > to`, and UUoC, not "please give me reasons why `cat` isn't a good substitute for `cp`".

Comment: @dnt, `tar` is the _tape archiver_. Many `tar` implementations still work with the first tape device by default.

Answer (score 1):

`< file1 > file2` Seems to be shell-dependent, on zsh it works, on bash not.

edit: deleted false statement

Comment: `cp -a` preserves the attributes of *file1* and *overwrites* the attributes of file2.  Opposite of desired behavior.  Plus I can't tell even by looking at the man page what will happen with hard links, but I think it's safe to say that *file2*'s hard links will *not* be preserved.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question careful enough.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the good answers, you can avoid a UUOC by *simulating* a `cat`:

```
awk 1 file1 > file2   # For line-oriented text, not binaries.
dd if=file1 of=file2  # Works for binary files, too.
# many more geeky ways.
```

These commands do not copy the file meta data, as a plain `cp` would.

Comment: True, but it's worth mentioning that they have no advantage and only drawbacks (performance, reliability) over `cat`. Here you do need a command to shove data between the two file descriptors and `cat` is one of the best one for that. See also `pv` which would be able to use `splice()` on Linux for fifos, (though it doesn't do `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL)` like GNU `cat` does).

Comment: The `dd` command for binary files seems good...or would `cat` work just as well for binary files?

Comment: @Wildcard `cat` also works for binary files (Unix generally doesn't distinguish; however, some tools specifically work line-by-line, such as awk, grep, wc, ... POSIX also defines a minimum largest line length, so in theory a line-oriented tool might refuse to deal with excessively large lines.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This answer also was intended as tongue-in-cheek. Seems like, despite the season, some people are allergic to fun (not directed at you; I value your shell expertise and Opengroup standards work).

Comment: `sed '' < file1 > file2` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If it works, don't fix it.

I would use

```
cat < file1 > file2
```

and not sweat the PC of the semantics.