# What metadata of a file does cp preserve by default?

Tags: cp, coreutils

By default, what file metadata does `cp` preserve, and what file metadata not?
For example, if I am correct, the mtime is changed, the access list is preserved, and I would to know about the other metadata (e.g. the other timestamps, ...).

I am looking up the manual of coreutils, but can't find the answer there.

Comment: You've seen the [POSIX standard for cp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)? It doesn't talk about ACLs, for example, so I think the specific implementation would vary. You may want to clarify if you're asking about the usage (or not) of the  `-p` flag.

Comment: specific to coreutils implementation ( do i need to mention ubuntu? i think coreutils is sufficient for specifying implementation?). default  behaviour, i.e. without explicitly specifying dedicated option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few months ago I [made a test](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249811/135943) of the behavior of `cp` when the target file already exists:

```
$ ls -li
total 12
913966 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:26 file1
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 39 Dec 16 20:35 file2
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 39 Dec 16 20:35 hardlinktofile2
$ cat file1
This is the contents of file1
$ cat file2
This is the original contents of file2
$ cp file1 file2
$ ls -li
total 12
913966 -rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:26 file1
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:37 file2
913965 -rwxrw---- 2 pete    vagrant 30 Dec 16 20:37 hardlinktofile2
$ cat file1
This is the contents of file1
$ cat file2
This is the contents of file1
$
```

As you can see, the target file is overwritten in place and *all* its permissions, ownership, attributes, etc. are preserved—even hard links.  The source file doesn't affect these in any way.

It wouldn't make any sense for `mtime` to be preserved by default, and it isn't.  But you'll notice that the new `mtime` of `file2` isn't taken from `file1`—it's taken from the current system time.

You could do a similar test without having the target file in existence already, but this test actually illustrates the point more clearly: **Only the actual *content* of the file is copied when no options are specified.**  File ownership, permissions, ACLs, mtime, et. al. are not set according to the source file, but instead are set in the same way they would be for a file newly created.  (So, permissions according to `umask`, `mtime` according to the current time, ownership according to the EUID of the `cp` process, etc.)

**There is one specific but common exception**:

> In the absence of [the --preserve=] option, the permissions of *existing* destination files are unchanged. Each *new* file is created with the mode of the corresponding source file minus the set-user-ID, set-group-ID, and sticky bits as the create mode. (The operating system then applies either the umask or a default ACL, possibly resulting in a more restrictive file mode).

---

According to `info coreutils 'cp invocation'`:

> ```
> `xattr'
>       Preserve extended attributes if `cp' is built with xattr
>       support, and xattrs are supported and enabled on your file
>       system.  If SELinux context and/or ACLs are implemented using
>       xattrs, they are preserved by this option as well.
> ```

This doesn't specify that extended attributes are preserved any other way than with this flag.