# Is there a POSIX shell which completely removes the need for `cat` and `dd` by using in-place operators?

Tags: shell, posix

In Vidar Holen's blog entry [Useless Use of dd](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=479), he argues that `dd` is 
effectively useless, primarily because everything is a file and files can be piped.

We have also seen regularly on all the *nix sites the active discouragement of using `cat`.

However, then Vidar puts forward this example:

```
# Rip a cdrom to a .iso file
cat /dev/cdrom > myfile.iso
```

...and I wonder, is it possible to do this *without using `cat`*?

Obviously, the POSIX shell is presuming that the first group of chars is a command (hence "["="test", etc) which is unusual in modern languages with in-place operators.  And, being as a shell is really an interpreter, why have we not got to the point where both `cat` and `dd` are redundant?

**Are there any POSIX-based shells which have fully implemented in-place operators to the point where just `/dev/cdrom > myfile.iso` would be enough to copy the data from a device to a file?**

**Or**

**Is there something in the POSIX specification which makes this kind of feature impossible?**

Note that this question is slightly different from the UUOC question in that the example still uses a command at the beginning ("<") and not in-place operators.  So it still conforms to the first-word-is-a-command rule.

(BTW, I personally like dd because, without it, speaking Welsh would be a lot less fun. :-p)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a UUOC (useless use of cat) to redirect one file to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249804/is-it-a-uuoc-useless-use-of-cat-to-redirect-one-file-to-another)

Comment: Works in zsh: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249872/70524

Comment: Vidar Holen ignores the fact that `dd` can be used both at the filesystem level and at the raw disk sector/block level.  For example, how would you use `cp` make a copy of an MBR?  Very easy to do using `dd`, i.e. `dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.backup bs=512 count=1`

Comment: `<` is not a command.

Comment: You can cook up some form of busybox shell including the requested functionality. But the whole idea of shell builtins is to streamline *very* frequently used commands (at the cost of inevitable incompatibilities, check e.g. the differences between the bash(1) builtin test with the standalone test(1)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zsh:

```
</dev/cdrom >myfile.iso
```

will do that with only operators (when not in `sh` emulation). It's still running the `$NULLCMD` command (`cat` by default) to do the actual reading and writing, though.

---

Your proposed syntax

```
/dev/cdrom > myfile.iso
```

could actually work *now* in any POSIX shell — because it doesn't necessarily implicate the shell at all.

What is required is that `/dev/cdrom` is executable, and that it outputs the contents of the CD when executed. That is something that your kernel or a device driver could provide. Alternatively, the system could have `execl` (and friends) use `/dev/cdrom` or its contents as a key to launch *another* executable (such as `cat`) with that filename.

In either case, with a suitably-`exec`able `/dev/cdrom` you'd be absolutely able to run that command in any shell. I don't know of any system that does behave that way, probably for very good reason, but it is theoretically permissible and possible.

---

## POSIX

POSIX requires that the first word of the command be treated as a command name, and [it defines how that command must be run](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> the shell shall execute the utility in a separate utility environment with actions equivalent to calling the execl() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 with the path and arg0 arguments set to the command name [...]
>
> If the execl() function fails due to an error equivalent to the [ENOEXEC] error, the shell [...] shall write an error message and shall return an exit status of 126.

It is thus not permitted for a conforming shell to open and print the file for data. There is no particular reason that a shell could not support that behaviour as a non-POSIX extension, however. I suspect that the form you propose has major drawbacks, but zsh's version is largely fine.

Comment: Great!  I thought so.  The second part of this answer is what makes in-place operators technically impossible.  So `cat` or any first-place operator can't be completely removed due to the POSIX specification, as I expected.  Nonetheless, with all the caveats in the first part it's nice to see that it's theoretically possible.